# What is the difference between installing WampServer versus components

Tags: wamp

What are the differences between installing an Open Source package that I found called WampServer versus installing each component separately (Apache, PHP, MySQL)?

I will be installing this on a Windows 7 laptop which is for development purposes.  The production machine is Linux although I've never had problems in the past just picking up my php code from a Windows machine and putting it on a linux machine.

Thanks ahead of time for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wamp is for quick setup of a developement enviroment. Wamp is also configured on a low security level. If you have an other production system, there is no need to install all the components separately.